# attaching events in datatable row in backbone view

Tags: backbone.js, datatable

i have a backbone view like this:

```
var newrow=Backbone.View.extend({

        el:"<table>",
        events:{
            'click .edit':'editrow',
            'click .delete':'deleterow'
            },


            render: function()
            {
                data=this.model.toJSON();
                $('table').dataTable().fnAddData([data.name,data.email,data.contact_number,'<span class="edit">Edit</span><span class="delete">Delete</span>']);
                return this;
            },

            editrow:function(){
                alert ("edit);
            },

            deleterow:function(){
            alert("delete");
            }
        })
```

I need to attach click events with td having spans with class 'edit'. I know this will not work because i am adding rows dynamically using datatable function. I am trying to add rows in a pre-rendered datatable. What may be the solution.

P.S I have already rendered a empty table in some other view. This works fine and datatable gets rows added. But can't figure out how to add click events in elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things are a bit off in your view. If you fix those, it might work.

- Instead of `el:"<table>"` try `tagName:"table"`. This is the [correct way](http://backbonejs.org/#View-extend) to set up a new element for a view.
- Instead of `$('table').dataTable()`. try `this.$el.dataTable()`. The former performs a selection for all table elements in you page, and the latter references your view´s (`<table>`) element.

As long as the elements you add are within the view's `el` the events should wire up automatically. If it doesn't work for some reason, try calling `this.delegateEvents()` after inserting new rows.

Comment: i didn't used tagName:"table" because i have already rendered the table and i so i am not creating a new element.

Comment: hey it worked. I did el:".dataTable" and then this.$el.dataTable(). Thanks for your help :)